# Why the prediction of profit is negative for the population less than 31125 using linear regression

Tags: machine-learning

i am beginner to machine learning and i have some doubt related to linear regression.here is the link of my repository https://github.com/utkarshmani1997/Machine_Learning/blob/master/exercise_1/exp1.ipynb

i was trying to predict the profit but it is giving negative values.What does it mean?

Comment: question your basis.  Can you have negative population?  Can you have infinite population?  These are fundamental questions to ask of the approach.  All models are wrong, but some models are useful.  Using a model without understanding its wrongness  is a synonym for voodoo.  ...  Where does one get the raw data?

Comment: I did not read your code,  but why would a higher population leading to a loss be as issue?  That ms

Comment: That makes perfect sense in many circumstances.

Comment: because profit = total revenue - expenses
thus expenses for that population ranges where profit is negative is due to higher expanses than that of revenue.i.e, profit is -ve.

Answer (score 0):

I got it. Actually, I was trying to predict only for range between 5k to 30k but when I tried for 35k, it gave me a positive result. This means that for that population range, there will be no profit. In other words, it is a loss.